# Temperature coefficient of a resistor

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, current-measurement

Is it correct to say that the current through a resistor is PTAT(proportional to absolute temperature) if it increase when the temperature increases?

[image]

Comment: According to the question title I assume you are asking/talking about changes of **resistance** vs. temperature. In the question body text you are talking about **current** (and in the graph you show **current and voltage** as labels for the y-axis). That's a complete different story as current not only depends on resistance but of course also on the circuit connected to the resistor and you don't mention anything about it (is it a constant voltage source? is it a constant voltage source with series resistance? etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say no.

The effects of temperature coefficient can be expressed as 
$$ R= R_0 \left[1 + \alpha\left(T_0-T_{\text{ref}}\right) \right]$$

So, only the  *change* in resistance (not the resistance) will be proportional to the temperature *difference*, and that holds best for small temp changes about a working point.

To be even more specific,
$$ R=\frac{\rho \ell}{A}$$

for objects with constant cross sectional area, where \$\rho\$ is resistivity, \$\ell\$ is length, and \$A\$ is cross sectional area.

Now, temperature will change the dimensions, and it will also change \$\rho\$.  From https://physics.info/electric-resistance/

> The general rule is resistivity increases with increasing temperature
>   in conductors and decreases with increasing temperature in insulators.
>   Unfortunately there is no simple mathematical function to describe
>   these relationships.

Thus, we tend to use the linear approximation for small temp changes, but work around a reference temp, as in the first equation presented.

Comment: In the shown graph even change in resistance is **not** proportional to temperature as the slope is obviously not constant.

Comment: @Curd -- I agree -- that's why I added the bit about linearizing about a small working area for small changes.  It's a pretty standard methodology.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct in general.

There are many ways that "quanity \$y\$ increases with quantity \$x\$", e.g.:

\$y=ax+b\$ (with \$a > 0\$) or
\$y=x^2\$ or
\$y=\sqrt x\$, etc.

If you say, however, "\$y\$ is **proportional** to \$x\$" you especially mean that the relation between the quantities is \$y= cx\$, where \$c\$ (slope) is a constant.

As you can see in your own example this is not the case as the graph is not a straight line (there is some curvature; the slope is not constant) and probably also not a line through the origin.

Comment: Even if the line did pass through the origin on that graph it would not be PTAT because the temperature is given in Celsius which (unlike Kelvin and Rankine) is not an absolute temperature scale.

Comment: Well, the OP did explicitly say absolute temperature (PT**AT**; the AT stands for **absolute temperature**). I consider the fact that Celsius scale is used just another (minor) sloppyness of the question...